# Rectangle Bounce collision detection

Tags: c++, sdl

I've created a program using SDL in which a rectangle continuously collides within the walls of the program, but the collision checking is not working properly.

Here is the code:`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//variable Initialization]
width = height = 45;
srcX = srcY = 0;
destY = destX = 0;
vlc = 1;
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
SDL_WM_SetCaption("Bouncing Balls","./ball.jpg");
backg = IMG_Load("./back.png");
ball = IMG_Load("./ball.jpg");
while (checkBounce){
    //Increase velocity
    destX += vlc;
    destY += vlc;
     //Collision Checking
        if (destX < 0){
            destX = 0;
            vlc = -vlc;
            destX += vlc;
        }
        if (destY < 0){
            destY = 0;
            vlc = -vlc;
            destY += vlc;
        }
        if (destY + height > 480){
            destY = 480 - height;
            vlc = -vlc;
            }
        if (destX + width > 640){
            destX = 640 - width;
            vlc = -vlc;
        }
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            checkBounce = false;
    }
//Applying Surfaces
applySurface(0, 0, backg, screen);
applyBall(srcX, srcY, destX, destY, width, height, ball, screen);
SDL_Flip(screen);
}
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

Here is the gif Image What is happening :[Bouncing Rectangle.gif](http://imgflip.com/i/2l2ep)

Comment: It would be nice if you could describe exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the expected result is for the rectangle to bounce off of the walls correctly?

You need to separate your velocity in to x and y components rather than using a single number. This is because velocity is two dimensional.

Your program is causing both the x and y components to become negative whenever a collision is detected. This causes the rectangle to bounce backwards along its path.

Here's an edit:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //variable Initialization]
    width = height = 45;
    srcX = srcY = 0;
    destY = destX = 0;
    vlcX = 1;
    vlcY = 1;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Bouncing Balls","./ball.jpg");
    backg = IMG_Load("./back.png");
    ball = IMG_Load("./ball.jpg");
    while (checkBounce){
        //Increase velocity
        destX += vlcX;
        destY += vlcY;
        //Collision Checking
        if (destX < 0){
            destX = 0;
            vlcX = -vlcX;
            destX += vlcX;
        }
        if (destY < 0){
            destY = 0;
            vlcY = -vlcY;
            destY += vlcY;
        }
        if (destY + height > 480){
            destY = 480 - height;
            vlcY = -vlcY;
            }
        if (destX + width > 640){
            destX = 640 - width;
            vlcX = -vlcX;
        }
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                checkBounce = false;
        }
        //Applying Surfaces
        applySurface(0, 0, backg, screen);
        applyBall(srcX, srcY, destX, destY, width, height, ball, screen);
        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```